# Arch in qemu: Does it hang on boot or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh, qemu

I'm not sure if Arch Linux (version of 05/02/2019) just hangs on boot while being emulated in qemu or if I just don't get how to use qemu.

Situation: I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server which I access via ssh. I would like to emulate arch using kvm and qemu (or any other suitable method).

There is just a command line access established to the server but no monitor. So I used the -curses option.

Full command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -enable-kvm -cdrom archlinux-2019.05.02-x86_64.iso -boot d -curses
```

This command boots arch into grub, where I selected the option:

```
Boot Arch Linux (x86_64)
```

This was the output:

```
Loading boot/x86_64/vmlinuz... ok
Loading boot/intel_ucode.img...ok
Loading boot/amd_ucode.img...ok
Loading boot/x86_64/archiso.img...ok
```

(There is a blank line at the end.)

From there on nothing else happens. Does arch hang or am I just using qemu incorrectly?

This warning pops up in the bash shell by the way.

```
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what happens in your case, but the svm warning is a red herring due to some old code we still have to carry for compat.

Answer (score 0):

This error is referring to CPU feature called LZCNT. It was introduced in Intel processors since Haswell (2013) and in AMD since 2007. So if your CPU is older or to any other reason does not support LZCNT - you will get this warning. You can check if your CPU support LZCNT instruction by executing the following command (Linux):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep abm
```

LZCNT can not be checked directly but it is included in the ABM flag (Advanced Bit Manipulations) which indicates both POPCNT and LZCNT are present. So if command output is blank - LZCNT is not supported.